# Magento - add files for custom module under system configuration

Tags: xml, magento, module, system

I have my own module in System->Configuration and want to add js and css files for it. 
Now it is so:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem"><type>js_css</type><name>prototype/windows/themes/default.css</name></action>
            <action method="addCss"><name>mymodule.css</name></action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

This way files added to all Admin pages. What to do to add this files just to one page, so write not default, but mymodule_admin or smth like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, you can use the `adminhtml_system_config_edit` handle, it would allow you to add your JS / CSS files on the system configuration pages only, as Magento does not provide finer layout handles for those pages.

But if you really need to add your styles to your system configuration form only, then you could either :

- add an event observer on `controller_action_layout_load_before` to add your own handle to the layout when the action is `adminhtml_system_config_edit` and when `Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/config_data')->getSection()` is corresponding to the section of your configuration
- add an event observer on `controller_action_layout_render_before_adminhtml_system_config_edit` that would directly add your JS / CSS files to the `head` block, when `Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/config_data')->getSection()` is also corresponding